# 2 ключа в одной таблице

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.
Нужно сделать так чтобы таблица trener_a4_6 была связана с таблицей metro_a4_6 через metro_id, но проблема в том что в таблице trener_a4_6 уже есть один первичный ключ. Как это можно сделать?

metro_a4_6

> Create table metro_a4_6
>     ( metro_id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY references trener_a4_6
> (metro_id)
>     ,metro varchar(20) not null 
>       ,tel varchar(20) not null
>     ,fax varchar(20) not null
>     )

trener_a4_6

> Create table trener_a4_6
>      (trener_id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
>     ,trener varchar(50) not null
>     ,salary money
>     ,metro_id int not null)

Будет ли такой вариант правильным:

> Create table metro_a4_6 ( metro_id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
> ,metro  varchar(20) not null    
> ,tel varchar(20) not null 
> ,fax varchar(20)  not null )
>
> Create table trener_a4_6   
> ( trener_id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY    
> ,trener varchar(50) not null    
> ,salary money  
> ,metro_id int not null FOREIGN KEY references metro_a4_6 (metro_id))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы внешний ключ не туда поставили...

```
Create table metro_a4_6
( metro_id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
 ,metro varchar(20) not null
 ,tel varchar(20) not null
 ,fax varchar(20) not null
)

Create table trener_a4_6
(trener_id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,trener varchar(50) not null
,salary money
,metro_id int not null REFERENCES metro_a4_6(metro_id))
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже понял свою ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Ну так у тебя сейчас связь `N:1`, определись какую связь тебе надо исходя из того что ты хочешь делать, а там уже останется только код написать. (нормализацию тактично упускаю)